# Interaction of C++ lambdas and templates

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++17

I'm trying to wrap my mind around the interaction of C++ lambda expressions and templates.

This code works as I expect:

```
#include <iostream>

int bar (int x, int (* f) (int))
{
    return f (x);
}

double bar (double x, double (* f) (double))
{
    return f (x);
}

int main ()
{
    std::cout << bar (16, [] (int x) -> int { return x * x; }) << std::endl;
    std::cout << bar (1.2, [] (double x) -> double { return x * x; }) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So does this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int bar (int x, std::function<int (int)> f)
{
    return f (x);
}

double bar (double x, std::function<double (double)> f)
{
    return f (x);
}

int main ()
{
    std::cout << bar (16, [] (int x) -> int { return x * x; }) << std::endl;
    std::cout << bar (1.2, [] (double x) -> double { return x * x; }) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So far, so good.  But neither of the following examples compile:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T bar (T x, T (* f) (T))
{
    return f (x);
}

int main ()
{
    std::cout << bar (16, [] (int x) -> int { return x * x; }) << std::endl;
    std::cout << bar (1.2, [] (double x) -> double { return x * x; }) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
T bar (T x, std::function <T (T)> f)
{
    return f (x);
}

int main ()
{
    std::cout << bar (16, [] (int x) -> int { return x * x; }) << std::endl;
    std::cout << bar (1.2, [] (double x) -> double { return x * x; }) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

GCC version 8.3.0 (with -std=c++17) gives an error message:

```
no matching function for call to 'bar(int, main()::<lambda(int)>' (and
another for the "double" version) and "template argument
deduction/substitution failed: main()::<lambda(int)> is not derived
from std::function<T(T)>" (for the second failing example).
```

However, this assignment works:

```
std::function<int (int)> f = [] (int x) -> int { return x * x; };
```

Could anyone please shed light for me?  (Obviously, this isn't practical code.  This is just an attempt to learn.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be not what you exactly need but it works with `C++11` (as [Lambda functions are just syntactic sugar for anonymous functors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)):

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename L>
T bar (T x, const L& l)
{
    return l (x);
}

int main ()
{
    std::cout << bar (16, [] (int x) -> int { return x * x; }) << std::endl;
    std::cout << bar (1.2, [] (double x) -> double { return x * x; }) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice!  This is the cleanest solution, I think.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that implicit conversion (from lambda to function pointer or `std::function`) won't be considered in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions); then in your 3rd and 4th sample type deduction for `T` on the 2nd function argument (i.e. the lambda) fails.

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), which happens later.

In this case `T` could be deduced from only the 1st function argument; you can declare the 2nd one with [non-deduced context](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts), to exclude it from deduction.

e.g.

```
template <typename T>
T bar (T x, std::type_identity_t<T (*) (T)> f)
{
    return f (x);
}

template <typename T>
T bar (T x, std::type_identity_t<std::function <T (T)>> f)
{
    return f (x);
}
```

PS: [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) is available from C++20, before that you can make one by your own, it's not difficult.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/m6Rgr05c2vYfQCSY)

Comment: Thank you.  I was unaware of std::type_identity_t being added in C++20.  (I admit I have not yet studied C++20.)  I'm afraid C++ is packing on weight faster that I am in pandemic quarantine! :-)

Answer (score 5):

Your failing code is expecting **function pointers** during template argument deduction and lambdas are not function pointers.

However, non-capturing lambdas such as yours can be converted to function pointers.

The most terse way to do this is to apply a unary `+`.  This works because a `+` is valid for pointers, triggering a conversion before template substitution occurs.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T bar (T x, T (* f) (T))
{
    return f (x);
}

int main ()
{
    std::cout << bar (16, +[] (int x) -> int { return x * x; }) << std::endl;
//                        ^ this is the only change
    std::cout << bar (1.2, +[] (double x) -> double { return x * x; }) << std::endl;
//                         ^ this is the only change

    return 0;
}
```

[See it compile on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/idufxQ)

Comment: Thank you.  I have to admit that if I had seen this code with the unary plus in front of the lambda, I would have had no idea what was going on.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case, do not forget this works too:

```
template <typename T>
T foo(T (*f)(T))
{
  return 0;
}

template <typename T>
T bar(T x, T (*f)(T))
{
  return f(x);
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << bar<int>(16, [](int x) -> int { return x * x; }) << std::endl;
  std::cout << bar<double>(1.2, [](double x) -> double { return x * x; }) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's, of course, one possible answer to the question "How to prevent issues in type deduction?" Don't use it. ;-)